# Clusters strategy different labelling at different level

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, clustering, animation

**What I did**

I am  trying to plot some points using cluster strategy of OpenLayers using [animatedCluster](https://github.com/acanimal/AnimatedCluster) plugin. I have gson data as given:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "SITESECTOR.1",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          83.01156083999999,
          29.12400297
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "SP_GEOMETRY",
      "properties": {
        "siteid": "S3 ",
        "zone": "Z1 ",
        "district": "D1 ",
        "MI_STYLE": null
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "SITESECTOR.2",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          82.60901315999999,
          28.707924959999996
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "SP_GEOMETRY",
      "properties": {
        "siteid": "S8 ",
        "zone": "Z8 ",
        "district": "D8 ",
        "MI_STYLE": null
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "SITESECTOR.3",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          83.917305,
          29.00006496
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "SP_GEOMETRY",
      "properties": {
        "siteid": "S4 ",
        "zone": "Z2 ",
        "district": "D2 ",
        "MI_STYLE": null
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "SITESECTOR.4",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          84.14876916,
          28.725629039999998
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "SP_GEOMETRY",
      "properties": {
        "siteid": "S5 ",
        "zone": "Z3 ",
        "district": "D3 ",
        "MI_STYLE": null
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "SITESECTOR.5",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          83.50468884,
          28.58398497
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "SP_GEOMETRY",
      "properties": {
        "siteid": "S6 ",
        "zone": "Z6 ",
        "district": "D6 ",
        "MI_STYLE": null
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "SITESECTOR.6",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          83.08200887999999,
          29.40729102
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "SP_GEOMETRY",
      "properties": {
        "siteid": "S1 ",
        "zone": "Z1 ",
        "district": "D1 ",
        "MI_STYLE": null
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "SITESECTOR.7",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          82.73984112,
          29.159415
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "SP_GEOMETRY",
      "properties": {
        "siteid": "S2 ",
        "zone": "Z1 ",
        "district": "D1 ",
        "MI_STYLE": null
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "SITESECTOR.8",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          83.24302895999999,
          28.619397
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "SP_GEOMETRY",
      "properties": {
        "siteid": "S7 ",
        "zone": "Z7 ",
        "district": "D7 ",
        "MI_STYLE": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "crs": {
    "type": "EPSG",
    "properties": {
      "code": "4326"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to **group these by it's property like zone or district** which are its attributed as well as other polygons and style it appropriately. And when there is only a single feature I wanted to label it with siteid. I tried without animated cluster and with Bbox strategy the labelling is fine but when I add animated cluster it all fails with **undefined** label.

My code:

```
var map;        
// Define three colors that will be used to style the cluster features
// depending on the number of features they contain.
var colors = {
                low: "rgb(181, 226, 140)", 
                middle: "rgb(241, 211, 87)", 
                high: "rgb(253, 156, 115)"
};            
// Define three rules to style the cluster features.
var singleRule = new OpenLayers.Rule({ 
                filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                                    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                                    property: "count",
                                    value: 1
                                }),         
                symbolizer: {
                    fillColor: colors.low,
                    fillOpacity: 0.9, 
                    strokeColor: colors.low,
                    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                    strokeWidth: 12,
                    pointRadius: 10,
                    label: "${siteId}",
                    labelOutlineWidth: 1,
                    fontColor: "#ffffff",
                    fontOpacity: 0.8,
                    fontSize: "12px"
                }
});
var lowRule = new OpenLayers.Rule({
                filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.BETWEEN,
                    property: "count",
                    lowerBoundary: 2,
                    upperBoundary: 15
                }),
                symbolizer: {
                    fillColor: colors.low,
                    fillOpacity: 0.9, 
                    strokeColor: colors.low,
                    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                    strokeWidth: 12,
                    pointRadius: 10,
                    label: "${count}",
                    labelOutlineWidth: 1,
                    fontColor: "#ffffff",
                    fontOpacity: 0.8,
                    fontSize: "12px"
                }
});
var middleRule = new OpenLayers.Rule({
                filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.BETWEEN,
                    property: "count",
                    lowerBoundary: 15,
                    upperBoundary: 50
                }),
                symbolizer: {
                    fillColor: colors.middle,
                    fillOpacity: 0.9, 
                    strokeColor: colors.middle,
                    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                    strokeWidth: 12,
                    pointRadius: 15,
                    label: "${count}",
                    labelOutlineWidth: 1,
                    fontColor: "#ffffff",
                    fontOpacity: 0.8,
                    fontSize: "12px"
                }
});
var highRule = new OpenLayers.Rule({
                filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.GREATER_THAN,
                    property: "count",
                    value: 50
                }),
                symbolizer: {
                    fillColor: colors.high,
                    fillOpacity: 0.9, 
                    strokeColor: colors.high,
                    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                    strokeWidth: 12,
                    pointRadius: 20,
                    label: "${count}",
                    labelOutlineWidth: 1,
                    fontColor: "#ffffff",
                    fontOpacity: 0.8,
                    fontSize: "12px"
                }
});           
// Create a Style that uses the three previous rules
            var style = new OpenLayers.Style(null, {
                rules: [singleRule,lowRule, middleRule, highRule]
});   

function init() {               
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
    var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                    "District Band", "/geoserver/wms/",
                    {layers: 'data:ICT_BND'}
    );
    var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {                    
                    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                        version: "1.1.0",
                        url:  "/geoserver/wfs",
                        featurePrefix: 'data', //geoserver workspace name
                        featureType: "sites",
                        featureNS: "www.wru.scl.com",
                        geometryName: "SP_GEOMETRY" 
                    }),
                    //new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()
                      strategies: [
                                        new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(),
                                        new OpenLayers.Strategy.AnimatedCluster({
                                            distance: 45,
                                            animationMethod: OpenLayers.Easing.Expo.easeOut,
                                            animationDuration: 10
                                        })
                                  ],
                    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap(style)
});

map.addLayers([wms, layer]);
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(85.522137, 27.629811), 10);
```

Intended Result:

**Different labelling at different points. First the label should be zone and then district and then siteid**

I am trying really hard to achieve this, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add event to zoom change in map object and change the style of layer.

Example

```
map.events.on({
    "zoomend":function(zoom=map.getZoom()){
        if(zoom==)//specify the condition
            layer.styleMap=//the style you want;
        else if(zoom>= && zoom<=)//next condition
            layer.styleMap=//another style
    }
})
```

You have already defined the styles, you just need to assign it based on zoom level.

Answer (score 2):

Using context, you can customise label text. This way you can display district, zone and siteid simultaneously. By defining many styles, you can only activate one at a time, i.e, either district, zone or siteid.

Here is an example

```
getgroup =function(feature){
    if(feature.count==1){
        return "single";
    }else if(feature.count>1 && feature.count<15){
        return "low";
    }else if(feature.count>15 && feature.count<50){
        return "medium";
    }else{
        return "high";
    }
};
var SingleStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
    fillColor: "${color}",
    fillOpacity: "${opacity}", 
    label: "${text}",
    context:{
        color: colors[getgroup(feature)],
        opacity: opacity[getgroup(feature)],
        text: function(group = getgroup(feature)){
            if(group=="single"){
                return feature.siteid;
            }else if(group=="low"){
                return feature.district;
            }else if(group=="medium"){
                return feature.district;
            }else{
                return feature.zone;
            }
        }
    }
});
```